# How to send a WAP Push with jsmpp

Tags: java, wap, smpp

I'm finding it difficult to send a WAP Push via jSMPP.

I need to know how to designate the UDH for jSMPP, and also how to specify that I'm sending a binary message.

Is there anybody with some sample code excerpt? I have tried without success for more some time, and I couldn't find any example by using google ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to send wap using sms, esmclass to 64 and datacoding to 245 would need to be set. You can try using the example below.

```
String messageId = session.submitShortMessage("CMT", TypeOfNumber.INTERNATIONAL, NumberingPlanIndicator.UNKNOWN, "55662", TypeOfNumber.ALPHANUMERIC, NumberingPlanIndicator.UNKNOWN, "your_phone_number", new ESMClass(64), (byte)0, (byte)1, timeFormatter.format(new Date()), null, new RegisteredDelivery(SMSCDeliveryReceipt.DEFAULT), (byte)0, new GeneralDataCoding(245), (byte)0, HexUtil.convertHexStringToBytes("0605040B8423F025060803AE81EAAF82B48401056A0045C‌ ​ 60D036578616D706C652E636F6D0007010377656C636F6D6520746F207761702073697465000101")‌ ​);
```

Comment: .. sounds interesting. Can you please format the code portions so it's human-readable?

Comment: There is not a constructor like GeneralDataCoding(int)

Comment: Is there another way to set datacoding to 245, it is because I think you have recompiled from source to add this contructor, so –